# Perl: how to cope with several condition

Tags: perl, if-statement

I would like to change a variable but if a first condition is true jump to the end of the if-block, respectively, do nothing. This pseudo code shows what I want:

```
if ( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {  # first condition
    $x = $x;
} 
elsif ( cond2 ) {         # second condition
    do something with $x;
}
elsif ( cond3  ) {        # third condition
    do something with $x;
}
```

I don't like the code above since I find it strange to assign the variable to itself. An other solution to avoid this self assignment is:

```
if ( $x !~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {
    if ( cond2 ) {            # second condition
        do something with $x;
    }
    elsif ( cond3  ) {        # third condition
        do something with $x;
    }
}
```

What I don't like on this code is that it is nested (what makes it complicated). I would like to have something like this:

```
if ( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {  # first condition
    stop here and go to the end  of the if block (END)
} 
elsif ( cond2 ) {         # second condition
    do something with $x;
}
elsif ( cond3  ) {        # third condition
    do something with $x;
} (END)
```

I know that there are commands *last* and *next* but as I understand these commands they works for getting out of a loop.

Any idea how to write a simple nice code for this problem?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Why do you think you have to do anything inside the code block?

Comment: @i alarmed alien: Because {} looks very odd but the longer I look at it the familiar it becomes.

Comment: You can always put a comment in it if you don't like the lack of content - it will help your future self and other users know why there isn't any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [basic block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Basic-BLOCKs) to exit your code

```
BLOCK: {

  if ( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {  # first condition
      # stop here and go to the end  of the if block (END)
      last BLOCK;
  } 
  elsif ( cond2 ) {         # second condition
      do something with $x;
  }
  elsif ( cond3  ) {        # third condition
      do something with $x;
  }
}
```

but since you're having elsifs you can omit code for first condition which would have same effect.

Comment: Thanks for this _basic block_. I didn't know about this. But I think for this kind of problem I just omit the code after if () {} as you mention. I wonder why you have been downvoted.

Comment: Please comment when down voting.

Comment: @giordano yes, in your case that is the best option.

Comment: In situations like this one might argue that `case`/`switch` constructs have a much cleaner look and feel. Having said that, I'd personally just stick with `if`/`elsif` and let the conditionals do the rest.

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken about how if-else works.

Where you wrote

```
if ( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {  # first condition
    stop here and go to the end  of the if block (END)
```

... that is exactly what *does* happen.

This (which you wrote):

```
if ( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {  # first condition
    $x = $x;
} 
elsif ( cond2 ) {         # second condition
    do something with $x;
}
elsif ( cond3  ) {        # third condition
    do something with $x;
}
```

is the same as this

```
if ( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ ) {  # first condition
    # do nothing
} 
elsif ( cond2 ) {         # second condition
    do something with $x;
}
elsif ( cond3  ) {        # third condition
    do something with $x;
}
```

When you understand this, what you are trying to to might seem more obvious.

Comment: How is it different from his second code block? `!( $x =~ /foo/)` and `$x !~ /foo/` are equivalent

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Thanks, that's it ( `if () {} elsif {do something} ...` ). I thought about this but I never saw it somewhere so I thought that there must be another way to do it. `!( $x =~ /^\d{4}$/ )` is not the same as `( $x !~ /^\d{4}$/ )`?

Comment: Whoa, you can stare at easy conditionals and stil get them wrong! My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You may like the idea of using `for` as a *topicaliser*, which shortens your regex matches as well as allowing you to use `last` to skip the whole block.

A lot depends on what `cond2`, `cond3` and `do something with $x` look like, but something like this could work

```
for ($x) {
   last if /^\d{4}$/;
   if ( cond2 ) {
       do something with $_;
   }
   elsif ( cond3  ) {
       do something with $_;
   }
}
```

or retaining the nesting and allowing `unless` as the regex pattern match is now a lot shorter

```
for ($x) {
   unless (/^\d{4}$/) {
      if ( cond2 ) {
          do something with $_;
      }
      elsif ( cond3  ) {
          do something with $_;
      }
   }
}
```